# R Assigning different colors and shapes to row.names in a NMDS plot

Tags: r, plot

I know there are different ways to assign shapes and colors to different groups of points in a plot. This is the way I have had success, except now I have my data formatted with row.names. Data looks like:

```
    row.names   Acidobacteria   Actinobacteria
1   Feb Fort Falls  258 232
2   Feb Fort Falls rep serum bottle 18  60
3   Feb Fort Falls serum bottle 88  68
4   Feb Tryptone Fort Falls 34  0
5   Feb Grass Fort Falls    1032    341
6   Feb Tree Fort Falls 121 730
7   July Fort Falls 31  271
8   July Fort Falls serum bottle    254 67
9   July Tryptone Fort Falls    337 50
```

... etc

My question is: How can I get the below code to work with row.names? When I just do 
attr(Brannen.diversity,"row.names")
This brings up the row names. But I can not get the shape and color of points to work with the way I have formatted code.

Code:

```
# vector holding the colors
cols <- c("red", "red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","red","red","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue")
shape <- c(18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17)
summary(shape)
# empty plot
plot(Brannen.ord, type = "n",axes=FALSE,xlab=" ",ylab=" ")
# Add points colored by Environmental Variable Management
points(Brannen.ord, col = cols[attr(Brannen.diversity,"row.names")], pch = shape[attr(Brannen.diversity,"row.names")])
text(Brannen.ord, col = "black", dis = "sp",cex=0.8)
plot(Brannen.ord.fac,p.max=0.05, cex.lab=4, cex.axis=4, cex.main=4, cex.sub=4)

# add legend
legend("bottomright",legend=levels(attr(Brannen.diversity,"row.names")), col=cols, pch = shape,cex=0.9,inset=0.1,bty="n",y.intersp=0.5,x.intersp=0.8,pt.cex=1.1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you're trying to subset `cols` with a character vector, but `cols` doesn't have any names.  Also, to the extent that `cols` is already ordered to match your data, can you just pass `cols` as the value for the `col` parameter?  If you `dput` the whole data.frame it might easier to give you an answer.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  I can get a legend similar to that just fine, but I haven't tried your specific levels and placement offsets.

Comment: BrodieG- you are correct, when I use just "col = cols" and "pch=shape" the points plot. However, now the legend gives me an error "Error in legend("bottomright", legend = levels(attr(Brannen.diversity,  : 
  'legend' is of length 0"

Comment: That suggests that you don't have any `levels` for the `attr` you called out.